# Steht „Herrn“ in einer Briefanschrift im Dativ oder im Akkusativ?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, accusative, address, written-language

Ich habe schon des Öfteren gelesen, dass das *Herrn* in einer Anschrift wie

> **Herrn**
> Otto Normalverbraucher
> Beethovenweg 9
> 48721 Gütersloh

ein Akkusativ sein soll. Begründet wird dies erstaunlich oft mit einem gedachten *an*, wobei nicht klar ist, wie oft diese Argumentation aus einer möglichen Urquelle kopiert wurde und wie oft sie dem Sprachgefühl des Verfassers entspringt. Beispiele:

> - [„Die Anschrift steht nach wie vor im Akkusativ und man schreibt Herrn Max Mustermann.“](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Profi-Tipps-fur-den-alltaglichen-Sprachgebrauch) (Duden.de)
> - [„Die Anschrift steht im Akkusativ. Es heißt also ‚Herrn Max Mustermann‘ (an wen?).“](https://www.morgenpost.de/kolumne/deutschstunde/article216871631/Herr-oder-Herrn-So-schreiben-Sie-eine-Adresse-richtig.html) (Sprachkolumne)
> - [„Beachten Sie bitte, dass es immer ‚Herrn‘ heißt und nicht ‚Herr‘. Denn gedanklich wird das ‚An‘ schon noch vor die Anrede gesetzt also: (An) Herrn Dieter Müller. Deshalb steht ‚Herr‘ im Anschriftfeld im Akkusativ (4. Fall) und wird damit zu ‚Herrn‘.“](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/herrn-oder-herr--was-ist-richtig#answer-128906497) (Frage-Antwort-Portal, möglicherweise aus Blog kopiert)
> - [„Man adressiert auf diese Weise, weil die Anrede im Akkusativ steht ... (An wen adressiert man den Brief? An Herrn Meyer.)“](https://christianwoellecke.de/herr-oder-herrn/) (Blog)

Umso erstaunlicher finde ich diesen Satz in der oben verlinkten *Sprachkolumne*:

> Der Dativ ist unüblich und kommt nur noch im diplomatischen Schriftverkehr oder bei bestimmten Ehrentiteln vor: „Seiner Eminenz, dem Hochwürdigsten Herrn Reinhard Kardinal Marx“.

Meines Erachtens ist *Herrn* nämlich genau das: ein Dativ, der angibt, *wem* das Schreiben gilt, *wem* es zuzustellen ist usw. Ich denke jedoch nicht, dass es sich hier um eine Auslassung (Ellipse) handelt, sondern vielmehr, dass dies *die* Domäne des Dativs schlechthin ist: angeben, *für wen* etwas ist; vgl. nur Inschriften wie *dem deutschen Volke* am Reichstagsgebäude. *Für das Volk* übersetzt sich zu *dem Volke*, *für Herrn X* übersetzt sich zu *(dem) Herrn X*.

Deutlich wird das Problem dann, wenn eine andere Bezeichnung dazukommt:

> Firma XY
> Dem/??Den Datenschutzbeauftragten
> Herrn Müller

oder auch

> Verein YZ
> Dem/??Den Vorsitzenden
> Herrn Schmidt

Wenn *Herrn* aus *An Herrn* folgen würde, so müsste das doch auch für *An Verein YZ, an den Vorsitzenden* gelten. Für mich wären diese beiden Beispiele jedoch eindeutig Pluralformen, nämlich Dativ Plural.

Auch vor dem Hintergrund (z.B. die Form *seiner Exzellenz*), den o.g. Kolumne nennt: Ist die häufig, auch im Duden anzutreffende Aussage, dass es sich um einen Akkusativ handle, haltbar, oder handelt es sich eindeutig um einen Dativ, wie mir mein Sprachgefühl nahelegt?

Comment: Ich stimme deinem Sprachgefühl und deiner Argumentation komplett zu, dass das ein  Dativ der Zueignung ist. Ich wüsste aber nicht, wie man das nachweisen sollte über die Argumente hinaus, die du schon genannt hast. Ein überzeugenderes Argument  als das genannte Beispiel "Seiner Eminenz, dem Hochwürdigsten Herrn Reinhard Kardinal Marx", das aus meiner Sicht eindeutig dafür spricht, fällt mir auch nicht ein.

Comment: Der relevante Vergleich ist mit möglichst vergleichbaren Wendungen, in denen der Unterschied *nicht* unsichtbar ist. Auf einem Gratulationsbrief etwa steht bisweilen "Dem Jubilar" oder "An den Jubilar", aber mit Sicherheit nicht "Den Jubilar"!

Comment: Früher hat man in der Anschrift tatsächlich "An Herrn Otto Normalverbraucher" oder "An Otto Normalverbraucher" geschrieben.

Comment: Intuitiv sehe ich es auch so wie du amadeusamadeus. Aufschluss kann hier nur die Sprachgeschichte geben. @Bodo, hast du einen Beleg für deinen Kommentar? Falls ja, wäre das in meinen Augen eine Grundlage für eine sehr gute Antwort.

Answer (score 6):

Früher hat man in der Anschrift tatsächlich

> An Herrn Otto Normalverbraucher

oder

> An Otto Normalverbraucher

geschrieben.

Ich bin 1968 geboren und kann mich aus meiner Kindheit an solche Anschriften erinnern, auch wenn das möglicherweise damals schon als veraltet galt.

Laut der nachfolgenden Quelle auch

> An das Finanzamt

entsprechend der Formulierung

> An den Verein YZ

in der Frage.

---

Im Internet habe ich bisher zwei Belege von der gleichen Quelle gefunden.

https://www.sekada.de/korrespondenz/anrede-und-anschriften/artikel/schreiben-sie-zeitgemaesse-anschriften-auf-ihre-briefe/

**Zitat (gekürzt):**

Noch immer landen bei mir in der Redaktion Briefe, zum Beispiel mit folgender Anschrift:

> An die Chefredakteurin Assistenz & Sekretariat heute
> Frau Angelika Rodatus

Oder:

> An Frau Angelika Rodatus

Dabei ist diese Form der Anschrift längst veraltet. Früher war es üblich „An das Finanzamt“ oder „An die Industrie- und Handelskammer“ zu schreiben. Heute lässt man Zusätze „An“ oder „An die/den“ weg.

[...]

Allerdings: Ein Muss ist die Anrede einer Person mit „Frau“ bzw. „Herrn“. Diese darf auf dem Anschriftenfeld nicht fehlen. Beachten Sie dabei auch, dass es immer „Herrn“ heißt und nicht „Herr“. Denn gedanklich wird das „An“ schon noch vor die Anrede gesetzt also: (An) Herrn Dieter Müller. Deshalb steht „Herr“ im Anschriftfeld im Akkusativ (4. Fall) und wird damit zu „Herrn“.

---

https://www.sekada.de/korrespondenz/anrede-und-anschriften/artikel/kniffligste-korrespondenzfragen-heisst-es-herr-oder-herrn-in-der-anschrift/

**Zitat:**

**Kniffligste Korrespondenzfragen: Heißt es Herr oder Herrn in der Anschrift?**

Das sagt der SekretärinnenBriefeManager dazu: Die Anrede „Herrn“ resultiert aus der nicht mehr aktuellen Anschriftenregelung „An Herrn“. Dabei handelt es sich um einen Akkusativ (Wen-Fall). Da der Akkusativ nach wie vor vorliegt, ist die Schreibweise „Herrn“ die einzig korrekte.

Falsch: Herr Claus Thieltges

Richtig:Herrn Claus Thieltges

Comment: *An* in der Anschrift kenne ich auch. Darauf berufen sich ja einige der Belege. Aber genau diese Herleitung stelle ich in Frage. Wie @KilianFoth unter der Frage kommentierte: "Auf einem Gratulationsbrief etwa steht bisweilen 'Dem Jubilar' oder 'An den Jubilar', aber mit Sicherheit nicht 'Den Jubilar'. So sehe ich das auch: Aus *An das Geburtstagkind* wird *dem Geburtstagkind*, da es sich meines Erachtens eben *nicht* um eine Ellipse handelt, sondern ohne Präposition der Dativ deren Aufgabe übernimmt.

Answer (score 5):

Es ist natürlich sehr schwer zu beweisen, dass etwas *nicht* ist.

Verweise auf die Vorgaben des Protokolls der BRD sind auch erst auf 1975 zurückzuführen ([Langfassung](https://www.protokoll-inland.de/SharedDocs/downloads/Webs/PI/DE/Allgemeines/Anschriften.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=1), [Kurzfassung](https://www.protokoll-inland.de/Webs/PI/DE/anschriften-anreden/anschriften/anschriften-node.html)). Hier der für die Frage wichtige Abschnitt:

> Bei der Anschrift wird auf das früher weithin übliche "An", "An den / die / das" verzichtet.
>
> Die in der ersten Zeile stehenden Anreden, Titel, Amts-, Berufs- oder Funktionsbezeichnungen stehen grundsätzlich im Akkusativ (Ausnahme z. B.: "Seiner Exzellenz dem Botschafter...").

Am besten lässt sich die Frage wahrscheinlich historisch beantworten. Dazu möchte ich einige Bilder zeigen. Teils nur als Link aus urheberrechtlichen Gründen. Die entsprechenden [Ganzsachen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganzsache) sind alle aus dem 19. Jhd.

[[image]Ganzsachenpostkarte aus dem Königreich Bayern (1895)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyK5q.jpg)

[Thurn & Taxis - Ganzsache ca. 1850 (1)](https://www.picclickimg.com/00/s/MTA2NlgxNjAw/z/dZ4AAOSwbdNf6IsE/$/Thurn-Taxis-Gansache-MIFs-Blau-und-Rot-_57.jpg)

[Thurn & Taxis - Ganzsache ca. 1850 (2)](https://www.picclickimg.com/00/s/MTA2NlgxNjAw/z/OFwAAOSwZq9f6IsJ/$/Thurn-Taxis-Gansache-MIFs-Blau-und-Rot-_57.jpg)

[Kaiserliche Reichspost ca. 1804](https://www.altpostgeschichte.de/core/index.php?attachment/64807-img446z-jpg/)

Wie man sieht sind all diese mit "An"  beschriftet. Daher denke ich, dass man davon ausgehen kann, dass das "Herrn" - außer bei oben genannten besonderen Ehrenbezeugungen - stets ein Akkusativ war.

Für weitere Informationen (oder Fragen) und auch einige der oben gefundenen Bilder schau in dieses Forum https://www.altpostgeschichte.de/

---

Fun fact: In der Schweiz wird es mehr und mehr üblich nur noch "Herr" zu schreiben.

Comment: Aber in allen Fällen folgt auf *»An«* kein Artikelwort, sondern eine Anrede. Beachte dazu, was ich in [meiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/63201/1487) über den Unterschied zwischen *»An **den Studenten** Karl Klein« (Anrede im Akkusativ)* und *»An **Student** Karl Klein« (Anrede trotz »an« im Nominativ)* geschrieben habe.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Oben unter "Langfassung" verlinkt lassen sich viele Beispiele für Anschriften finden. Bei (fast) allen gilt das zitierte "Anreden, Titel, Amts-, **Berufs-** oder Funktionsbezeichnungen stehen grundsätzlich im Akkusativ". Evtl findest du entsprechende offizielle protokollarische Vorgaben für Österreich, die davon abweichen. Österreich ist ja bekannt dafür Titel sehr ernst zu nehmen. Oder welche für die Schweiz, denn wie geschrieben ist es dort mittlerweile üblich nur noch "Herr" zu schreiben.

Answer (score 3):

Die Frage ist ja, ob es sich überhaupt um einen der beiden Fälle handelt. Anstelle des Wortes *»Herr«* könnte ja auch ein Grad oder Titel stehen, wobei hier auch eine simple Berufsbezeichnung als Titel durchgeht.

Nehmen wir an, das Wort *»Student«* wäre ein Titel. Dieses Wort wird wie folgt dekliniert:

> Nom: Der mit der Brille ist **der Student.** **Der Student** lernt.
> Gen: Der Tutor nimmt sich **des Studenten** an. Das Auto **des Studenten** ist rostig.
> Dat: Der Richter glaubt **dem Studenten.**
> Akk: Der Prüfer hört **den Studenten.**

Das Wort endet also in allen Fällen außer dem Nominativ auf *-en.*

Auf einem Briefumschlag kann man daher schreiben:

> <sub>Dativ</sub>
> **Dem Studenten** Karl Klein
> Holzweg 8
> 1020 Wien

> <sub>Akkusativ</sub>
> An **den Studenten** Karl Klein
> Holzweg 8
> 1020 Wien

Aber schon wenn man im letzten Beispiel den Artikel weglässt, wird die Sache anders:

> 1. An **Studenten** Karl Klein
>    ...
> 2. An **Student** Karl Klein
>    ...

Ich würde bereits hier die Version 2 der Version 1 vorziehen. Wenn man dann auch noch das Wort *»an«* weglässt, wird die Tendenz zur Version im Nominativ noch stärker:

> 1. **Studenten** Karl Klein
>    Holzweg 8
>    1020 Wien

> 2. **Student** Karl Klein
>    Holzweg 8
>    1020 Wien

Das geht nicht nur mit *Student*, sondern auch mit *Dirigent, Musikant, Rivale, Proband, Pirat, Katholik, Idiot, Therapeut, Fotograf, Biologe, Brite, Chinese* und noch mindestens einem Dutzend anderer Wörter, die sich als Pseudo-Titel eignen und im Dativ und Akkusativ auf *-en* enden.

Zum Beispiel auch der ...

- Monarch

  > Dat: Ich glaube **dem Monarchen.**
  > Akk: Ich sehe **den Monarchen.**

  > **Dem Monarchen** Hans-Adam II
  > Bergstraße 2
  > 9490 Vaduz, Liechtenstein

  > An **den Monarchen** Hans-Adam II
  > Bergstraße 2
  > 9490 Vaduz, Liechtenstein

  > An
  > **Monarch** Hans-Adam II
  > Bergstraße 2
  > 9490 Vaduz, Liechtenstein

---

Das Problem an der ganzen Sache ist ja, dass Grammatik die Kunst ist, Wörter zu ganzen Sätzen zusammenzufügen. Wenn man aber gar keine ganzen Sätze produziert, sondern nur Fragmente, dann verlässt die Grammatik ihr Definitionsgebiet. Da wird dann fast alles möglich. Daher würde ich Adressanschriften als eine separate Kategorie betrachten, die nur eine gewisse Ähnlichkeit mit grammatischen Fällen in ganzen Sätzen hat, damit aber nicht zu 100% übereinstimmt.